# In a kendo grid, can I set column attributes dynamically with a function?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I've got some code here where I am trying to set a background color of a cell based on the value of the data item: http://dojo.telerik.com/@solidus-flux/eHaMu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    title: "Name",
    attributes: function(e) {
      return {
        "class": "table-cell",
        style: e.name == "Jane Doe" ? "background-color: red" : "background-color: green"
      };
    }
    //attributes: {
      //"class": "table-cell",
      //style: "text-align: right; font-size: 14px"
    //}
  } ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I realize I could do this with a template, but that would require an extra html element, since you can't change the markup of the td itself. I'd like to use a function to return attributes if that is supported.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You said you don't want to use templates, but I think you were talking about column templates.

You can change the markup of the td itself by using a row template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-uid="#= uid #">
      # this.columns.forEach(function(col) { 
          var val = data[col.field],
          css,
          style = ''
          cClasses = ''; 
          if (typeof col.attributes === 'function') {
              css = col.attributes(data); 
              cClasses = css["class"];
              style = css.style
          } 
      #         
          <td class='#= cClasses #' style='#= style #'>
            #= data[col.field] #
          </td>
      # }) #
    </tr>
</script>
```

For the loop to work, you need to bind your template to the grid though:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "name",
        title: "Name",
        attributes: function (e) {
            return {
                "class": "table-cell",
                style: e.name == "Jane Doe" ? 
                       "background-color: red" : "background-color: green"
            };
        }
    }, {
        field: "title",
        title: "Title"
    }],
    dataSource: [{name: "Jane Doe", title: "Dr. Dr."}, 
                 {name: "John Doe", title: "Senior Citizen"}]
}).data("kendoGrid");

var template = kendo.template($("#template").html()).bind(grid);
grid.setOptions({
    rowTemplate: template
});
```

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/aYAXI))

As an alternative, you could also create attributes like this:

```
{
    field: "name",
    title: "Name",
    attributes: { 
        "class": "# if(data.name === 'Jane Doe') { # red # } else { # green # } #" 
    }
},
```

This would have the advantage of not using the row template, but you'd have to use the template syntax for the logic.

([demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/oGOMa))

Comment: If the attributes property does not support functions, then this gets me as close as I am going to get.

Comment: now that you say it, you can use functions in the attributes as long as you don't mind the template delimiters (and having to write it as a string)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .greenBG {
            background-color:green;
        }
        .redBG {
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [{
                field: "name",
                title: "Name",
                attributes: function (e) {
                    return {
                        "class": "table-cell",
                        style: e.name == "Jane Doe" ? "background-color: red" : "background-color: green"
                    };
                }
            }],
            dataSource: [{ name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }],
            dataBound: function () {
                dataView = this.dataSource.view();
                for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
                    if (dataView[i].name === "Jane Doe") {
                        var uid = dataView[i].uid;
                        $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("greenBG");
                    }
                    else {
                        var uid = dataView[i].uid;
                        $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("redBG");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got it working with something similar: `$("td").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() === "Jane Doe") {
                        $(this).addClass("good");
                    }
                });` but I was hoping not to have a loop. Just an attribute by function.

Answer (score 0):

In angular kendo callback e not work

Use this

```
attributes: {
                    "ng-confirm-message": "{{this.dataItem.is_active ? \'Are you sure deactive ?\' :  \'Are you sure active ?\'}}",
                    "confirmed-click": "vm.inlineSubmit(this.dataItem.toJSON() ,true)"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kendo-JQuery.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
    field: "name",
    headerAttributes: {
      "class": "table-header-cell",
      style: "text-align: right; font-size: 14px"
    }
  }]
});
</script>
```

And this Kendo-MVC

```
.Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ActiveReason).Title("ActiveReason").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table-header-cell" });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Some years later but ... **the attributes function is not working at all for me**, is not even hit, seems pretty but not working (Why is needed a manual class toggle if a functions is provided to do the work? something seems weird).

I make editable cells based on other fields values but also I needed to change the styles

1) Add the validation on field that you want to  inject the css class,

```
//Your other fields configuration
field:"dependentField",
attributes:
{
    "class": "# if(data.ImportantField!==true) { # nonEditableCellStyle # } else { # editableCellStyle # }# ",
}
//Your other fields configuration
```

2) Bind the  grid change event and check if some important field has changes, if is the field that controls the style of other cells just call the refresh method

```
var _kendoGrid = $('#myGrid').data("kendoGrid");

_kendoGrid.dataSource.bind("change", function (e) {
    if (e.action === "itemchange") {
        if (e.field === "ImportantField") {
            _kendoGrid.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

The refresh method will render your grid again, that means your functions weather is a template or an attribute function ( and again, that does not work at all for me) will run and apply the correct sytles, or classes in this case.